# LEFT JOIN in LINQ between dbContext and InMemory List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

My tagNumbers is of  `List<string>` type. I need to do a left join on this List with database. Currently when I start a trace on database, I see as many queries getting fired as many no of records are in this list. Also this LINQ query gives an error when using LEFT JOIN i.e. `lj.DefaultIfEmpty()` since l.TagId will be NULL in case of LEFT JOIN for some of the records

i.e. 
`SELECT * FROM tagNumbers LEFT JOIN TagCollections ON.....LEFT JOIN...`

```
from t in tagNumbers
join tc in dbContext.TagCollections on t equals tc.TagNumber into lj
from l in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join m in dbContext.MapTagEntities on l.TagId equals m.TagId    
select new GetItemByTagnumberResponse
{
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

1. How should I ensure only one query is fired on database no matter how long my list is.
2. How should I correct my LEFT JOIN from getting an exception

Error
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on `join m in dbContext.MapTagEntities on l.TagId equals m.TagId` l.TagId because "l" is NULL in case of LEFT JOIN where join condition is not matching.

Comment: You can not join inmemory list with db table...

Comment: do you really want an answer? I bet that no one has your exact models and data to test this query and see the exception themselves. By skimming  over the query, it looks fairly fine but currently there is no understanding about your models.

Comment: @KingKing Based on your comment, I simplified the LINQ query. tagNumbers is my in memory list while other two are database tables. I need to get all tagNumbers irrespective of my join in `SELECT`. While for matching tags, I need corresponding data as well.

Comment: You mentioned about an error but why not post what it is here? Even your query is very short, no one really cares to try it in a temp project. In other words your problem is unclear. If you have error, it should be posted with its message, otherwise if it runs fine, describe what's unexpected in the result.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using GroupJoin. Here is simple implementation.

```
        // When
        var results = fruitIds
            .GroupJoin(db.Fruits, id => id, fruit => fruit.Id, (id, fruits) => new
            {
                id = id,
                fruit = fruits.FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .GroupJoin(db.Attributes, f => f.fruit != null ? f.fruit.Id : 0, att => att.Id, (fruitContainer, attributes) => new
            {
                id = fruitContainer.id,
                fruit = fruitContainer.fruit,
                attribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .ToList();

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(3, results.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Where(r => r.fruit != null).Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Where(r =>  r.attribute != null).Count());
```

Sorry for fruit implementation, I had it already written, I just needed to do proper query.